# fading of images in iphone from resources

Tags: objective-c

what I want is to fade the first image and show the next one.. I ve got 3 images in resouce
bundle i was able to fade from first image to the next and then the appcrashes giving an error in the console..NSInvalidArgumentException-[NSCFString objectAtIndex:]:Unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5e...below is the code ..cud u guys help me.

in header

```
UIImageView *imageViewBottom, *imageViewTop;

NSArray *imageArray;
```

implementation

```
int topIndex = 0, prevTopIndex = 1; 
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  imageViewBottom = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
  [self.view addSubview:imageViewBottom]; 

  imageViewTop = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
  [self.view addSubview:imageViewTop];

  imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"lori.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"miranda.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"taylor.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"ingrid.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"kasey.png"], 
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wreckers.png"], nil];


  NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5.0 
                                              target:self 
                                            selector:@selector(onTimer) 
                                            userInfo:nil 
                                             repeats:YES];

  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
  [timer fire];

  [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)onTimer
{    
  if(topIndex %2 == 0)
  {   
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^    
    {
      imageViewTop.alpha = 0.0;
    }]; 
    imageViewTop.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:prevTopIndex];

    imageViewBottom.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:topIndex];
  }
  else
  {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^       
    {     
      imageViewTop.alpha = 1.0;
    }];        
    imageViewTop.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:topIndex];

    imageViewBottom.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:prevTopIndex];
  } 
  prevTopIndex = topIndex; 

  if(topIndex == [imageArray count] - 1)
  {
    topIndex = 0; 
  }
  else
  {
    topIndex++; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]` is autoreleased so when you try to access you are picking up garbage

you need

```
imageArray = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:  
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"lori.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"miranda.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"taylor.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"ingrid.png"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"kasey.png"], 
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wreckers.png"], nil] retain];
```

dont forget to release in the dealloc

```
-(void)dealloc
{
[imageArray release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

**[Edit]About the timer and comments**

Try using

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 
                                              target:self 
                                            selector:@selector(onTimer:) 
                                            userInfo:nil 
                                             repeats:YES];
```

Rather than

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5.0 
                                              target:self 
                                            selector:@selector(onTimer) 
                                            userInfo:nil 
                                             repeats:YES];

  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
  [timer fire];
```

I have a feeling your construct is locking the thread somehow. I might be wrong.

```
-(void)onTimer:(NSTimer *)aTimer
{
...
}
```

Is also the preferred signature.

Comment: @WarrenBurton:thanks dude..dat totally worked..but now i m facing another problem where ..ive got a table view below my imageview ..due to the transition of images i m not able to navigate from one view to another in table view..its like the screen is frozen i m not able to do any operation excepting the continous transiton of images

Comment: do your images overlay the tableview? do some magic with userInteractionEnabled and maybe subclass the imageview so you can override the – hitTest:withEvent: or – pointInside:withEvent: methods

Comment: its like dis...i have placed a tableview in uiviewcontroller and above the tableview i m doing the  fading of images..i m getting the fading transition infinitly but the entire view is frozen..if i m to use an NSoperation or (threading) of the above fading of images..i m getting the transition of first two images untill the web data gets loaded in the table view..after the webdata gets loaded in table view the fading transition is stoped and the frozen view is released(i m able to acess tableview stuff)...wat i want is fading of images to occour infinetly at the same time access other stuff

Comment: kind of a different question but im not a score whore :) see edited answer

Comment: @warren:k...u r calling -(void)onTimer.. in the selector...but wat about the argument that is to be passed....(NSTimer *)aTimer..cud u please reedit the code for passing the argument at the selector..i tried the above code..der was no image..

Comment: theres a difference between @selector(onTimer:) and @selector(onTimer) in the former case the argument is the timer which is scheduled. You dont provide the argument. See the docs for scheduledTimerEtc